# C#: MWArray SEHException

Tags: c#, arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

```
public static void EnergyandEntropy(List<float> data, string _filename, OpenFileDialog open)
        {
    NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(open.FileName));
            byte[] mainBuffer = new byte[wave.Length];
            int sampleRate = wave.WaveFormat.SampleRate;

            int window_ms = 200;
            int window;
            int fs = sampleRate;
            window = window_ms * fs / 1000;

            float[] fbuffer = new float[mainBuffer.Length / 8];
            wave.Read(mainBuffer, 0, mainBuffer.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < fbuffer.Length; i++)
            {
                fbuffer[i] = (BitConverter.ToSingle(mainBuffer, i * 8));
            }

            data.AddRange(fbuffer);
            int dataRange = data.Count - (data.Count % window);
            data.RemoveRange(dataRange, data.Count - dataRange);
            var rows = window;
            var cols = data.Count / window;
            float[,] array2D = new float[window, data.Count / window];
            var current = 0;   
            List<double> abc = new List<double>();
            List<double> cba = new List<double>();
            List<double> vuv = new List<double>();
            List<MWArray> ent = new List<MWArray>();
            MWNumericArray arr1;
            EntropyCalculation obj = new EntropyCalculation();
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    array2D[i, j] = data[current++];
                    double a = array2D[i, j] * array2D[i, j];
                    abc.Add(a);
                    cba.Add(array2D[i, j]);
                    arr1 = cba.ToArray();
                    if (abc.Count % rows == 0 && abc.Count > 0)
                    {
                          double energies = Math.Sqrt(abc.Sum());
                          MWArray result = obj.entropy(arr1);
                          abc.Clear();
                          cba.Clear();
                          arr1 = null;
                          vuv.Add(energies);
                          ent.Add(result);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

I have this code and using a MatLab function that name is entropy.m (I converted it dll). I am calculating the energies and entropy of data segments. To do this i fill data inside `List`. When my data reaches the number of rows i clear lists and MWArray. Then it continues to process next segment.

Here is my problem. While calculating entropy of small files it works fine. However when i try to calculate entropy of files that size greater than 10 megabytes `arr1 = cba.ToArray();` this line throws an exception. `SEHException was unhandled` - `External component has thrown an exception.` I tried to put some break points then observed the code. It works at the beginning of the loop but then gives me that exception. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
        NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(open.FileName));
        WaveFileReader wavFile = new WaveFileReader(open.FileName);

        int sampleRate = wave.WaveFormat.SampleRate;
        byte[] mainBuffer = new byte[wave.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 5];

        #region Constraints
        int window_ms = 200;
        int window;
        int fs = sampleRate;
        window = window_ms * fs / 1000;
        #endregion

        int read;
        int length = (int)wave.Length;
        List<double> listOfEnergies = new List<double>();
        List<MWArray> ent = new List<MWArray>();
        MWNumericArray arr1 = null;
        EntropyCalculation obj = new EntropyCalculation();
        if (wave.Length % mainBuffer.Length != 0)
        {
            int value = (int)(wave.Length / mainBuffer.Length);
            length = mainBuffer.Length * value;
        }
        while (wave.Position != length)
        {
            List<double> segment = new List<double>();
            List<double> listOfSquaredSegment = new List<double>();
            read = wave.Read(mainBuffer, 0, mainBuffer.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < read / 8; i++)
            {
                segment.Add((BitConverter.ToSingle(mainBuffer, i * 8)));
                double segmentSquare = segment[i] * segment[i];
                listOfSquaredSegment.Add(segmentSquare);
                //arr1 = segment.ToArray();
            }
            arr1 = segment.ToArray();
            double energy = Math.Sqrt(listOfSquaredSegment.Sum());
            listOfEnergies.Add(energy);
            MWArray result = obj.entropy(arr1);
            ent.Add(result);
            arr1 = null;
        }
```

I was getting SEHException. It arises from "Function evaluation is disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out". I found its resource. If you try to fill your `MWNumericArray` in `for` loop it could not complete the process so evaluation timed out. I also changed my code to process bigger files. It still a bit slower but it works fine for now.